# how to get the text inside the dynamically rendered items on the click of the button?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am displaying the content after fetching it via ajax using jquery so the content is dynamic,

```
var i, j;
var product_names = [];
var product_image = [];
var product_rate = [];
var product_amount = [];
var product_category = [];
$.ajax({
    url: BASE_URL + '/getOrgServices?orgId=' + orgId,
    type: 'GET',
    success: function(result) {
        //console.log(result);
        for (i in result) {
            product_names[i] = result[i].name;
            product_image[i] = result[i].imgurl;
            product_rate[i] = result[i].rate;
            product_amount[i] = result[i].amount;
            product_category[i] = result[i].categories;
        }

for(i in product_category){
                var html = '<div class="prod-content"><ul id="products">';
                html += '<li class="row product-listing">';
                html += '<div class="product-img-container"><img class="product-img" src="' + product_image[i] + '"></div>';
                html += '<div class="container product-listing-details"><h6 id="product-title">' + product_names[i] + '</h6><div id="product-description">' + product_amount[i] + '</div><br><div id="product-cost">' + product_rate[i] + '</div></div>';
                html += '<div id="product-add">';
                html += '<button class="add-button" type="button" role="button">ADD</button>';
                html += '<span class="quantity"><input class="item-quantity" type="number" value="0" min="0" max="50" step="1"></span>';
                html += '</div></li> </ul></div>'
            
                //adding elements to all category
                var id_str = '#' + new_id[0];
                $(id_str).append(html);
 }

}
```

Now in the below function i want to access the name of one h6 product_name at a time so is there any method to do so like if I could select

```
$(".add-button").click(function() {
        //here i want to add items to cart on button click (means the button clicked its corresponding item should be added to cart )
   });
```

is the cart part of the html code

```
  <div class="order">
      <ul id="products">
       <li>
          //here i want to append the added item
       </li>
     </ul>
   </div>
```

Comment: id has to be unique. You are running a loop and creatingaUl with same id, which is wrong. Same thing goes for h6, the isd has to be unique.

Answer (score 1):

To get all h6 you can do similar thing as below, without jQuery.

```js
$(".add-button").click(function() {
  console.log("click");
  document.querySelectorAll("div.prod-content h6").forEach((function(elem) {
    console.log(elem.innerText);
    if (parseInt(elem.innerText) > 0) {
      console.log(elem);
    }
  }));
});
```

Comment: but i want to get the product_name of one specific element not the whole list.

Comment: actually i am trying to show the selected elements in the cart section therefore needed the name of that specific item only

Comment: That's fine you can compare  `if(parseInt(elem.textContent)>0){ console.log(elem)})`

Comment: will try and let you know sir

Comment: no it did not work, it is not able to get the name of  the current element for which button is clicked

Comment: `$(".add-button").click(function() {
              console.log("click");
              document.querySelectorAll("div.prod-content h6").forEach((function(elem){
                //console.log(elem.textContent);
                if(parseInt(elem.textContent)>0)
                {
                     console.log(elem);
                }
              }));
            });`

Comment: I have edited my answer, please check now. and let me know what it prints in the console log

Comment: it prints all the item names

Comment: Also I am thinking of doing it by dynamically changing the ids of elements and then accessing it, will it be a right way to do it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220416/discussion-between-asutosh-and-vinita).